# ssrs derived Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a lot of reports which have the same parameters (datetime custom period forexample). For each new report I have to recreate  list of parameters.

Is there any option to derive parameters from base report?
Or maybe it is possible to add similar parameters simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a template report with all the basics (params, headers etc).

Then in BIDS, choose to add an existing report item, browse and select the template report you created.

Reporting services will copy the template rld file to the project folder and add the report to the BIDS solution explorer.